# How to open a new window in FULLSCREEN with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using this code but it doesn't work because the new window is half of the my screen ( 1280x800px ):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '', 
'fullscreen=yes');">Open Full Screen Window</a>
```

Why ?

Answer (score 6):

In browsers which supported it in the first place, this feature has been phased out due to its user hostility and ability to be used for phishing security attacks.

> **fullscreen**
>
> Do not use. Not implemented in Mozilla. There are no plans to implement this feature in Mozilla.
>
> This feature no longer works in MSIE 6 SP2 the way it worked in MSIE 5.x. The Windows taskbar, as well as the titlebar and the status bar of the window are not visible, nor accessible when fullscreen is enabled in MSIE 5.x.
>
> fullscreen always upsets users with large monitor screen or with dual monitor screen.  Forcing fullscreen onto other users is also extremely unpopular and is considered an outright rude attempt to impose web author's viewing preferences onto users.

— https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open